# Threads created by Executors.newCacheThreadPool is not daemon though the pool created within a Daemon

Tags: java, java-8, daemon, executorservice

To avoid passing in a custom `ThreadFactory` to the `ThreadPoolExecutor` to use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool();` directly.

I created a thread `mainDaemonThread`, use the `Executors.newCachedThreadPool();`, submit tasks and before `mainDaemonThread` is started, I set it `daemon` and as far as I know, once the **parent** thread is a daemon then all threads it created will be `daemon` in default.

[Daemon Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

> When code running in some thread creates a new Thread object, the new thread has its priority initially set equal to the priority of the creating thread, and is a daemon thread if and only if the creating thread is a daemon.

So why the `Executors.newCachedThreadPool();` is not following the rule? Some design preference related to this?

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread mainDaemonThread = new Thread(() -> {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            try {
                out.println(Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                out.println(Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
            } catch(InterruptedException ignored) {
                ignored.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    });
    mainDaemonThread.setDaemon(true);
    mainDaemonThread.start();
    mainDaemonThread.join();
    out.println(Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
}
```

The output for the demo:

```
false
false
false
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you ~

Comment: that rule applies if you do a new Thread from a daemon thread. If a custom thread factory is intervening in between, it might have its own semantics. That's the reason why the API allows you to pass your own thread factory to override all these rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is not really a proper answer as to why, but:

The document you link is for the `Thread` class and documents the behavior of "manually" creating a new `Thread`. It just does not apply to the tasks you submit to an `ExecutorService` (although I can see why you would expect that).

If you look into the source, the `newCachedThreadPool` executor uses an (internal) `DefaultThreadFactory` which explicitly creates a non-daemon `Thread`:

```
public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
    Thread t = new Thread(group, r,
                          namePrefix + threadNumber.getAndIncrement(),
                          0);
    if (t.isDaemon())
        t.setDaemon(false); // ta-da
    if (t.getPriority() != Thread.NORM_PRIORITY)
        t.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
    return t;
}
```

If you want the executor to create a daemon thread, you can use the `Executors#newCachedThreadPool(ThreadFactory)` method with a factory that does create daemon `Thread`s. Since `ThreadFactory` is a functional interface, this is as simple as

```
Executors#newCachedThreadPool(Thread::new);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But still I wonder why the `DefaultThreadFactory` will reset the `daemon` and `priority`. It is kind of `protective` mechanism to make sure the **developer** really understand what he/she is about to do?

Comment: @Hearen Well, I can only give an educated guess. A daemon thread doesn't prevent shutdown if it's not terminated. When an executor starts a thread, that is considered a work thread that needs to be given the opportunity to finish, whether started by a daemon or not.

Comment: @daniu to name a counter-example, a Fork/Join pool creates only daemon threads by default. But what these thread pools have in common, is that the policy is consistent and not depending on the creator of the worker threads, as the creator is unpredictable. Each thread submitting a job *may* be the creator of a worker thread when the queue is full and the maximum count not reached. If the submitter threads have different properties, the properties of the worker threads should not become unpredictable. That’s a comprehensible idea.